# Jekyll blog in Rails site using Bloggy gem: how do I use the Rails css for the blog, on each build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, jekyll

I've got a Rails site with a Jekyll blog incorporated, using the [Bloggy](https://github.com/zbruhnke/bloggy) gem.

I'd like a similar look for the main site and the blog, so I want to use the css in app/assets/stylesheets, but those files are in css.scss format. Jekyll (in a Bloggy setup) looks for css in config/jekyll/css, and seems to only want .css files; symlinking the Rails css directory into the Jekyll hierarchy doesn't seem to to work.

Is there a way to take advantage of the asset pipeline so that when I run jekyll:build, SCSS files from the Rails app are made into CSS files, placed in the appropriate jekyll directory, and bundled with the latest Jekyll build as it's placed into the /public/blog folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up getting through this by:

- Using the [jekyll-sass](https://github.com/noct/jekyll-sass) gem to allow automatic transformation of the Rails app's .css.scss into .css.css files. By symlinking the Rails app/assets/stylesheets directory into Bloggy's config/jekyll/css, this put files with the right content but wrong extensions in the correct place.
- Writing a rake task to make the .css.css files into .css files.

  ```
  desc 'Make .css.css files into .css files'
  task :css_css do
       Dir.glob('public/blog/css/*.css.css').each do |file|
           puts `mv #{file} #{file.gsub(/\.css\.css$/, '.css')}`
       end
  end
  ```

Not the prettiest solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew.. You have a nice solution.. For this part I did some stuffs manually. Like I added config/jekyll/css files as .css extension rather than .css.scss so when we run "rake generate" for bloggy the right format files are created on the folder public/blog/ rather css.scss.

I have made the changes in my [bloggy portfolio theme project](https://github.com/antodoms/portfolio-blog) repository. If you are planning to use my version of code, I have did some changes like added robots.txt, sitemap, and integrated bootstrap to the project. I have also removed all database connections from the rails project since it was showing errors while deploying into heroku.